# Having trouble with execvp

Tags: c, shell, execvp

I am having some trouble with a basic shell program I am trying to write in c. Whenever I try calling exec in a function such as **ls**, execvp will return with an error stating that the file or directory could not be found. I think that the problem is with the parsing because in main, the command can be printed but in the function it is blank. Thanks

Here is the code for the function :

```
int extern_process(char *arg[]){
    pid_t pid;
    int errnum, ifFail;
    printf("i%si\n",arg[0]);
    pid = fork();

    if(pid == -1){
        errnum = errno;
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: fork %s", strerror(errnum));
        return FAIL;
    } else if(pid == 0){
        ifFail = execvp(arg[0],arg);
        if(ifFail < 0){
            errnum = errno;
            fprintf(stderr,"Error: exec %s", strerror(errnum));
            return FAIL;
        }
    } else {
        pid = wait(NULL);
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the code for the parsing function just in case:

```
void parse_cmd(char *retval[], char *cmd){
    char *tmp;
    char a[100];
    strcpy(a,cmd);
    int i = 0;
    tmp = strtok(a," \n\t\0");

    if(retval == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error with allocation\n");
        return;
    }
    if(tmp == NULL){
        printf("Error with parsing.\n");
        return;
    }
    while(tmp != NULL){
        retval[i] = tmp;
        tmp = strtok(NULL," \n\t\0");
        i++;
    }
    retval[i] = NULL;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
shell> ls 
ls
i i 
Error: exec no file or directory found
```

Comment: but according to your code, `i i` means that the command which you trying to execute is empty.  So, your arguments to the `extern_process` look wrong. You need to provide the code which calls the function.

Comment: will not completely empty, perhaps a space `" "`. Also `" \n\t\0"` is redundant, should just be `" \n\t"` (String constants already end with a `'\0'`).

Comment: when this: `parse_cmd()` returns, the `char *retval[]` will contain pointers into the local array: `a[100]` However, that array will be 'out of scope'  when the function exits so accessing it is undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `ifFail = execvp(arg[0],arg);`  This is not correct, Suggest: `execvp(arg[0],arg);  perror( "execvp failed" )' exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  do not `return;` as the child process will be executing and you do NOT want the child process to return to the caller of the function: `extern_process()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure strtok returns a pointer that refers to that first argument which, in your case, is a stack allocation.  Returning an array of pointers to that stack allocation would result in undefined behavior, I believe.  This may or may not be the cause of your problem.  It's difficult to know without seeing more of the code.  To test, try changing this part of your code like this:

```
void parse_cmd(char *retval[], char *cmd){
    char *tmp;
    char *a = strdup(cmd);
    int i = 0;
```

Before using it in production, you need to work out some way to ensure that you free "a" or you'll get a leak.  Maybe you could just return it instead of void and free it from elsewhere, or you could actually strdup() each token and write a function to free them all or whatever works for you.

If there are other problems, they may be in other code.  I don't really see anything else wrong here.

Comment: Thank You, I tried this and it seemed to clear up my problems.